# argument type 'object' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to remove a drawing from my winform.
What is wrong with my code?

```
  private void removeDrawing()
    {
        foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
          if (ctrl.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer")
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(ctrl); // argument type 'object' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control
            }
        }
    }
```

[Update]
Thanks for the answer.
I implemented it as

```
while (this.Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>().Any())
        {
            var ctrl = this.Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>().First();
            this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll still have to cast `ctrl` to the correct type, but I wouldn't recommend doing type checking by name. Try this instead:

```
private void removeDrawing()
{
    foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        var shapeContainer = ctrl as ShapeContainer;
        if (shapeContainer != null)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(shapeContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

However, a little Linq can help you out here. See the [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
using System.Linq;
...

private void removeDrawing()
{
    foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<ShapeContainer>().ToList())
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
    }
}
```